# Returning inserted rows in presto

Tags: sql, presto

I'm am inserting rows from one table to another using presto, and would like the inserted rows to be returned. Something like this...

Something like:

```
insert into animals    
select * from arriving_animals
returning *
```

It appears `returning` is not supported in presto. Any advice on how to return the rows that are inserted within the same statement?

Answer (score 0):

Create a "temporary" table with the rows to insert:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_insert AS
SELECT * FROM arriving_animals
```

Then insert them:

```
INSERT INTO animals
SELECT * FROM tmp_insert
```

You can now read the inserted rows and drop the table when finished.